# Advise for implementing a php image proxy

Tags: php, image, proxy

I need to implement a proxy in PHP for loading image files, I found something like this

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    if (isset($_POST['remote_url'])) {
        echo file_get_contents($_POST['remote_url']);
    }
?>
```

(1) Is there any better way to do this? or enhance this? (in terms of speed & server loading)

(2) How to avoid unauthorized usage for this PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

(1) I'd add some error handling, at least. Fetching remote resource might end with a timeout, 404 or any other HTTP error. And this, in turn, might make you switch from `file_get_contents` to CURL, which has much more configuration options. And some tests show that it works faster than `file_get_contents`, by the way.

(2) If you use sessions, it might be suitable here for authorization. Another (but less reliable) option is checking `HTTP_REFERER` header contents.